# Have constructor resolve to an existing instance

Tags: c#, constructor, instantiation

I'm curious if there's a way to tell a class being constructed to reference an existing instance.

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    string _name;

    static List<MyClass> _existing = new List<MyClass>();

    MyClass(string name)
    {
        foreach(MyClass existing in _existing)
        {
            if (existing._name == name)
            {
                // Set this instance to "existing"
                return;
            }
        }
        _name = name;
        _existing.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to take a singleton-like approach. Perhaps make the constructor private and implement a method called GetOrCreateMyClass (or whatever) and have that either return the found instance, or construct and return a new one with the private constructor. At least that's what it looks like you might want, at a glance.

Comment: What I'm doing is I have a particle creation system that only allows a single instance of any given particle type. So when a new particle is created, if it's type-signature matches that of an existing particle, the existing particle is returned and a new one isn't created. I know I could do this with additional functions, but I was hoping there was a way to maybe use Reflection or something to change the address of the constructing item to be. It's merely an attempt at reducing my code. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: "_It's merely an attempt at reducing my code_" But you are not really reducing your code. You are just trying to move it from a factory method into a constructor and then "fool" the object creation mechanism behind `new`. So instead of having the same code in the factory method, you would have the same code plus the code "fooling" the `new` (if that were actually possible, which it is not).

Comment: The simple answer is **no**. You cannot make `new MyClass(...)` return anything but a new object reference for a reference object ("`class`"). But if you can share details about your class and _why_ you're trying to do this, there are some interesting options available. For example, if a particle is defined entirely by its type signature, you could make it a `struct` to avoid instantiating anything on the heap and making all particles with the same type equal to one another.

Answer (score 2):

I'm  not sure if this the best approach to solve your real problem, because this sounds like a typical xy-problem. Maybe you should get familiar with singletons or dependency injection where you can control this in detail.

However, to solve this concrete issue you could use a `Dictionary<string, MyClass>`:

```
class MyClass
{
    string _name;

    static Dictionary<string, MyClass> _existing = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

    private MyClass(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public static MyClass GetFromName(string name)
    {
        if(_existing.TryGetValue(name, out MyClass instance))
            return instance;

        MyClass newInstance = new MyClass(name);
        _existing.Add(name, newInstance);
        return newInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the way I already do it. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it in the constructor. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanPlumb: you are looping a list to find an item. This is returning it directly from a dictionary which can be a huge performance gain. No, it's not possible from a constructor  to return something, because a constructor is just used to initialize this instance(fields + properties). That's why i'm using a static factory method with a meaningful name and "hide" the constructor ny making it private, so no one can create an instance without the factory method that encapsulates the instance check.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement a holder of the particles, that can direct creation or re-use to existing objects. The constructor of each class, cannot be responsible to see if it already exists, since merely newing it up to inspect, allocates resources for it. Your particle holder (Single instance) would then use a dictionary/hash/list/collection to return existing based on name, or create and cache new instances for future use.